# WIX Custom Action on Dialog

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I want to add and custom action after NEXT in LicenseAgreementDlg I and using WixUI_FeatureTree

and I want to implement sothing like this but how and where ??

```
<Property Id="prerequisites_insta" Value="command line to run"/>
<CustomAction Id="prerequisites_insta" Directory="Setup"
 Impersonate="no" Return="ignore"
ExeCommand="[Setup]Prerequisites.exe -install" />

<Publish Dialog="LicenseAgreementDlg" Control="Next" Event="DoAction" 
Value="prerequisites_insta">NOT Installed</Publish>
```